# What signature is expected for the filter function when you apply filter on a List[(String,Int)]?

Tags: scala

This will not compile

```
object TestFilter extends App {
  val a = List(("orange",0), ("peach",1), ("apple",2), ("banana",3))
  filter( (i:String,j:Int) => j % 2  == 0)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(6, 30) type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Int) => Boolean
 required: ((String, Int)) => Boolean
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is of type `List[(String, Int)]`. The type `(String, Int)` is a pair (`Tuple2`). This pair is the argument in the filter-function.

You can write it in two ways. The first way is this:

```
list.filter(pair => pair._2 % 2 == 0)
```

You can also use pattern matching on the pair. This will get you closer to what you want:

```
list.filter { case (i, j) => j % 2 == 0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The type expected is `Tuple2[String, Int]` [Tuple2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html).
In order to accomplish the filter on the second parameter you have 2 options:

`val a = List(("orange",0), ("peach",1), ("apple",2), ("banana",3))
a.filter{case (i,j) => j % 2 == 0}`

or

`val a = List(("orange",0), ("peach",1), ("apple",2), ("banana",3))
a.filter(_._2 % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

a is a List of Tuple2:

```
val a = List(("orange",0), ("peach",1), ("apple",2), ("banana",3))
a.filter(t => t._2 % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: So when I write `(i:String,j:Int) =>` it does not take a Tuple2 as argument ?

Comment: It's not a legal formal parameter. Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.

Comment: @ThomasLehoux Huh? `t => t._2 % 2 == 0` is also an "anonymous function". What do you mean?

Comment: Anonymous means that the function is not named, in both cases it is not named, correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: @BlueTrin Yep. I was just confused at what difference it made here, when both options are anonymous functions.